# Problem with Google Ad Manager set up : google returns code 3 error when requesting ads

Tags: java, android, admob, adsense, google-ad-manager

Trying to retrieve ads from Google's Ad Manager , and while i have followed the official Mobile Ads SDK implemetation , i can not get these ads. To be more specific, when i send the ad request , i get the following object as answer:

{
"Code": 3,
"Message": "No ad config.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null",
"Response Info": {
"Response ID": "null",
"Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
"Adapter Responses": []
}
}

What is weird about that is that when i am using AdMob ( instead of AdManager ) ,ads are served correctly. Also, i am referring to testing ads , as my app is not yet on production.
Another important thing , is that when i am requesting test ads from AdManager, when i am using the AdManager's sample ad units, ads are served. But when i am setting my device as a testing device programmatically, and request ads from my own ad unit, the above error occur ( which, as i foretold is not the case for AdMob, as with AdMob i am getting ads in both these scenarios. The error indicates that i may have done something wrong when setting the ad units on the AdManager UI , but i really have followed the documentation step by step. What might be the problem ??

---

***UPDATE*** :
I have managed to get banner ads and native styles ads , but i still can not get native ads to use custom rendering or interstitials. I suspect that this might has to do with setting the ad unit's size. A prerequisite to make and ad request for banner ads or native styles ads , is to set a specific ad size from within the application's code, which is not the case for custom rendering or interstitial ads. However, inside AdManager UI , while i set the ad unit and try to get the ad unit id to use it inside the application's code, i have noticed the following small text:
**"You will need to include an ad unit size in your application code."**
This is not the case when someone wants to custom render native ads or to play interstitial ads ( meaning that the Mobile Ads SDK does not offer methods to set the ad unit size when making a request ).
So , is it possible that Google has a bug , and despite the fact that i make a request for interstitial ads or native ads, it still require to set an ad unit size ?????

---

**UPDATE 2** :
As it seems, at least in my case, i can not receive testing ads from the ad unit i have set in Google Ad Manager ( for native ads ) by setting my device as a testing device using the mobile ads sdk , so in order to test the app, i made a testing campaign with my own assets to serve to my mobile app...